# Magento: Empty response from Paypal API IPN Endpoint

Tags: php, magento, paypal

Good afternoon,

A client of ours received an email notification early this morning stating:

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

https://www.domain1.com/paypal/ipn

https://www.domain2.com/paypal/ipn

I took a look at the code handling these endpoints and found that an exception is being thrown due to an empty response from the following endpoint:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Code in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php(133):

```
protected function _postBack(Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Interface $httpAdapter)
{
    $postbackQuery = http_build_query($this->_request) . '&cmd=_notify-validate';
    $postbackUrl = $this->_config->getPaypalUrl();
    $this->_debugData['postback_to'] = $postbackUrl;

    $httpAdapter->setConfig(array('verifypeer' => $this->_config->verifyPeer));
    $httpAdapter->write(
        Zend_Http_Client::POST,
        $postbackUrl,
        '1.1',
        array('Connection: close'),
        $postbackQuery
    );

    try {
        $postbackResult = $httpAdapter->read();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_debugData['http_error'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode());
        throw $e;
    }

    /*
     * Handle errors on PayPal side.
     */
    $responseCode = Zend_Http_Response::extractCode($postbackResult);
    if (empty($postbackResult) || in_array($responseCode, array('500', '502', '503'))) {
        if (empty($postbackResult)) {
            $reason = 'Empty response.';
        } else {
            $reason = 'Response code: ' . $responseCode . '.';
        }
        $this->_debugData['exception'] = 'PayPal IPN postback failure. ' . $reason;
        throw new Mage_Paypal_UnavailableException($reason);
    }

    $response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $postbackResult, 2);
    $response = trim($response[1]);
    if ($response != 'VERIFIED') {
        $this->_debugData['postback'] = $postbackQuery;
        $this->_debugData['postback_result'] = $postbackResult;
        throw new Exception('PayPal IPN postback failure. See ' . self::DEFAULT_LOG_FILE . ' for details.');
    }
}
```

I set up a sandbox version of the same site and, while payments are being processed, I am still receiving an empty response from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Because the response is empty, an exception is being thrown and the response header is being set to 503 Service Unavailable which is what I believe triggered the email our client received.

I've seen a few similar questions on here but nothing conclusive as to what is actually causing the response to be empty? Is this an issue with Paypal, or has something gone wrong our end? For completeness, we recently conducted a move to a new server (though this issue only seems to have arisen in the last day or so).

Answer (score 0):

So after promising myself I had exhausted my enquiries, I seem to have jumped the gun on myself.

Our firewall had whitelisted api-3t.paypal.com, which is the endpoint for most other API calls.

BUT, as you can see above, this one request is going to www.paypal.com (or www.sandbox.paypal.com)

To make it worse, I added www.paypal.com to the firewall but not www.sandbox.paypal.com which meant my sandbox environment was erroring even though I had "fixed" the production environment...